# Ampliy withAuthenticator v/s with withOAuth

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

AWS Amplify withAuthenticator v/s with OAuth

I want to implement an authentication mechanism for react app. I am using AWS Amplify framework, It provides 3 methods either use custom UI or with the authenticator and with OAuth components. I see with OAuth component provides Cognito hosted UI while withAuthenticator component provides AWS Amplify Custom UI.

What are the pros and cons of both except the UI

Answer (score 5):

`withAuthenticator` is email & password against Cognito User Pools where the user is created in that directory. `withOAuth` and `Auth.federatedSignIn` use the OAuth endpoint of Cognito User Pools for OAuth flows, which performs redirects for you to authenticate users against a social provider such as Login With Amazon, Facebook, Google Sign-In, etc. A corresponding user account will be created in Cognito User Pools directory after this process takes place. More info can be found here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#concepts

Comment: How they are different on the basis of security?

Comment: @Richard can amplify library achieve CIP and Google integration (without involving CUP) like this https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a/2017/06/18/CognitoDiagram.png?